# Get email address from Facebook log in

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

Today I tried to make a Facebook login from iOS app. I followed the developer.facebook.com guide but I have a problem. I want to get the email address of users that are logged in. Searching on web I found the function [user objectFromKey @"email"] but it doesn't work for me. This is my code:

```
@interface FLTViewController ()

@end

@implementation FLTViewController
@synthesize profilePictureView;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize statusLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    FBLoginView *loginView =
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes",@"export_stream"]];


    loginView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
    self.nameLabel.text = user.id;
    self.statusLabel.text = [user  objectForKey: @"email"];
}


- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = @"";
    self.statusLabel.text= @"You're not logged in!";
}

@end
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error? Return nil? Something else?

Comment: the problem is that statusLabel is empty but nothing error